# Computer is lagging and software keeps running out of memory at 50% usage

Tags: windows-10, memory

Computer is using 2x 32GB RAM cards. However, it's been ridiculously slow at 50% usage, and some apps are crashing with "out of memory" errors.

[image]

more disk info as requested in comments:

[image]

Comment: Are any of your apps 32 bit as they can only see approx 4gb of RAM?  Did you disable your swap file by chance?

Comment: Disk is 0%.  Are you running a live image in memory?

Comment: @cybernard I always select 64 bit when prompted. The Figma app I'm using only has one version, so I'm guessing 64 bit: https://www.figma.com/downloads/

Comment: @stark added screenshot of disk. i think it'll only go above 0% if i'm saving or exporting something

Comment: i'm going to try this next i think: https://www.robertmullaney.com/2018/08/29/windows-10-memory-usage-capped-fifty-percent-50/

Comment: When did this happen? When you first got the computer? After installing software? After updating Windows or software? *Which* apps are out of memory, and is that consistent?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I haven't had it yet but I've also never got memory usage this high before. All apps are slow around this usage.

Comment: I have been suffering from a similar issue for the last few years and incidentally I just posted a similar question https://superuser.com/questions/1720203/google-chrome-not-taking-advantage-of-all-ram-on-windows-10 I notice those problems during browsing.